# Why changing the type of my data doesn't reduce the size of my parquet?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, storage, parquet

I'm running some experimentations to reduce the size of my parquet files.
I have a 6 columns in type float64 with nan in each column that I want to export into parquet. The parquet file after exportation with the columns with the float64 format has a size of 23555KB.

First experimentation converting the columns into float32 I got the same size 23555KB for the parquet.

```
df[list_column]=df[list_column].astype('Float32')
df[list_column].to_parquet("Float32.parquet")
```

Second experimentation converting the columns into int64 same result.

```
df[list_column]=df[list_column].astype('Int64')
df[list_column].to_parquet("Int64.parquet")
```

Third experimentation fill the nan with -999 and convert into int16 I    got a parquet file with a size 23980KB.

```
df[list_column]=df[list_column].fillna(-999)
df[list_column]=df[list_column].astype('Int16')
df[list_column].to_parquet("Int16.parquet")
```

I don't understand why after converting my float64 columns into smaller format I got parquet with the same size or even bigger for the int16.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM32Z.png)

Comment: Hi Rob404, please consider sharing a [mcve]. Then when you change dtypes you mostly change the memory usage not size on disk.

Comment: Thank you @rpanai I will try to share one, thank you for the information do you mean to change the type will not affect the size of the files? If yes it will probably answer my question.

Comment: Capital `I` `Int16` is a pandas extensionarray which supports NA values. What happens if you try with `int16`?

Comment: @Rob404 i confirm.

Comment: @creanion no improvement with int16, thank you @rpanai!

Comment: Compression is enabled by default, I think. How does that affect it?